# Drawing a line over a chart

Tags: c#

I have a C# chart with several columns. I want to connect the YValues of the columns with a line. I haven't found in the internet a solution that helps me, all the solutions I have seen only added a new column next to my original columns.

Comment: I have tried to add a new series to the chart called line with different BorderDashStyle, but it only adds a column to my chart.

Comment: Each point in the chart has a YValue, the value of the column. In my case its a chart of profits in the last quarter, divided by months. I want to draw a line from one column to the next, to show increase/decrease of profits between months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second series with the same data points and ChartType "Line" as "overlay"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above. These might be useful commands with some helpful syntax that you're looking for

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; //Goes to top in declarations

graph.Series.Add("line overlay");
graph.Series["line overlay"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```